# Change the location of the cache folder NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, caching, next.js, frontend

currently the cache folder is inside "./.next/cache" I wonder if it is possible for me to change the location of this cache folder.

The reason I do this: I am working on an application with large numbers of daily accesses, and I am going to upload more than one application from my FrontEnd. Ideally, all of these applications should share the same cache folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible at this stage.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10111

Edit: From one of the contributors

> Can you solve this by symlinking you CI's cache sub folder to .next/cache? An option you are suggesting may be a source of many bugs and questions, hence is generally undesired.

In my case symlinking worked well.

Edit: Summary

The reason this is not possible is because

> [the functionality] may be a source of many bugs and questions, hence is generally undesired.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon, this answer could be improved by summarizing the contents of the link as well :)